# Compiled packages and apt-get mess

Tags: 12.04, apt, compiling, gcc, gdb

Due to my work I have to use the last version of gdb (7.7) which is not provide in the ubuntu repositories. For that purpose I download the source code, compiled it and installed it successfully.

My question comes with the fact that apt does not know that I am using that version of gdb so whenever there is an small update it will downgrade gdb to the version which is existing in the repositories.

In short, I wonder how should I deal to get two version in my system of the same package, one the older version from the repository, and the new version from the compiled source code.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits.

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean?  If you don't want the one from the repositories, then remove it.

Comment: The problem is that im sharing that server with more people and they demand me to keep the old version

Comment: Then apt is already doing exactly what you want; keeping the stock version... your self compiled version should be installed into /usr/local.

Comment: So the apt version, where is it going to be installed? In /usr?

Comment: Yes.. normally when you self compile software they use a /local suffix so they don't conflict with the version provided by the distribution.

Comment: So in such case, how can I differentiate both of the version in the PATH variable? Is it there any trick or just change the name of the binary?

Comment: PATH is searched in order, or explicitly specify the full path to the one you want.